# About '&nbsp'. How to prevent break word

Tags: html

I thought `'&nbsp;'` prevent to break word.

But it doesn't work as I expected.

```
<div>
  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBBB &nbsp; CCCCCC
</div>
```

[image: the result]
But I thought it will be like this.↓

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 
BBBBBBBB  CCCCCC
```

because break word between 'BBBBBBBB' and 'CCCCCC' is prevented.

But the result is as you see,

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBBB  
CCCCCC
```

depends on window size.

How can I prevent break word using `'&nbsp;'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the "normal" spaces around `&nbsp;` - so:

```
<div>
  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA BBBBBBBB&nbsp;CCCCCC
</div>
```

`&nbsp;` is a space itself, it does not affect surrounding white-spaces.

Comment: Ahhhhh, I see. I was so stupid!!! So I was trying to prevent break word between normal spaces!!!! HaHa! Thank you!!!

Comment: Great, so if that helped you I kindly ask to mark my response as "Answer" so it helps other people to instantly know that this has been resolved.